# Tag # 7804 in Fix protocol

Tags: fix-protocol

I have seen Fix messages with a tag name and value like  7804=PSD7
But I couldn't find any reference for tag 7804 on https://www.fixtrading.org/
What could this tag mean? Is it part of a standard fix protocol or a custom tag?

Separately is there any good resource for learning about Fix protocol and its subtlety
How should one go about it? Like, are there any bookish Questions Answer things that one
could practice and learn in-depth or any open source projects that one could start
looking into or some problem one could take up and solve that could automatically lead
to understanding.

Comment: Seems to be a user-defined tag, which is bad since they normally should be from a higher range of numbers. You should ask the counterparty what a tag this is. Open source FIX enginges: if you are using Java take a look at QuickFIX/J. Otherwise QuickFIX (C++) or quickfixn (.NET).

Comment: @ChristophJohn Thanks, that makes sense. Is it documented somewhere about the user-defined tags and what range we should use?

Comment: Sorry, I have to correct myself. I mixed up the 10000+ field range. Actually fields between 5000 and 9999 are also user defined. You can read about it here: https://www.fixtrading.org/online-specification/introduction/#user-defined-fields and here is a list of user defined fields that have been registered: https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/user-defined-fields/

Comment: @ChristophJohn, I checked the pdf that you mentioned. It has a 7804 tag with Field=Algo Reserved, Description=Algo reserved - APAC Product, Created by = Billy Zhao - Deutsche Bank. Is there any explanation for these?

Comment: I am afraid you'll have to ask the counterparty that uses these.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the vanilla FIX data dictionary is merely a suggestion.

The reality is that every counterparty makes custom changes to the message and field definitions ("the data dictionary").  Every single one.  In a 10+ years with FIX, I've not met one that doesn't.

When writing an app using one of the QuickFIX engines, the first thing you need to do is to get ahold of their FIX interface specs, read them, and edit your FIXnn.xml data dictionary file to match.  Sometimes counterparties will provide this file for you.

Comment: So, to learn more about the subtlety of Fix, do you suggest I should start exploring QuickFix Engines in Java, etc. Any other resource apart from this? Separately when there is a user-defined tag in FIX, can the standard FIX parser handle such things?

Comment: I'm biased, because I'm the maintainer of QuickFIX/n and have been a contributor to QuickFIX/j .  If QF has been supplied with an accurate DataDictionary xml file, then it can parse custom fields, certainly.  But you may need to use the generic FIX accessor methods to get them (e.g. `msg.GetString(7804)` instead of `msg.GetMyCustomFieldName`) unless you regenerate a new API from your DD and rebuild a new dll.

Comment: @nickshetty https://www.fixtrading.org/beginners-resources/